# Can sublime text build results be searched?

Tags: sublimetext3

I tried to select all --> copy --> paste to a new file, but the output is big, only a portion of the output copied. 
Is there any way to search from the build results?
or at least, how I can copy all the output to a new file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to search the build results directly, but you can easily copy and paste. Once the build is complete, click in the build pane, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on Windows/Linux (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on OSX) to select all. Next, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy. Open a new file, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste, and you can now search the results. I'm not sure why your previous attempt at selecting all didn't work, for as far as I know the amount of data that can be copied to the clipboard is only limited by available memory. Unless your output contains gigabytes of data (in which case you should be writing to a file anyway...), this method should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! My build never end because last script just monitor the output from resin web server. Not sure if this is the possible reason...